# Sum.if, without nesting 12 sum.if functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem with an excel function, i "inherited" from a former colleague.
I have the two tables below:

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

My goal is to get the green field in Table 2 to show the sum of Person1s earnings from January to December. If months was =11 in Table 2, it should show the sum of Person1s earnings from January to November.

My current formular is a lot of nested "If" and "Sum.if" functions, but i wish to shorten it. Is it possible. I tried to say the sum area in the Sum.If to be all columns with data, but it still just returns the one from january (the first one it finds, i guess)

I hope someone can help me! Sorry for my bad english, but i'm not a native speaker

Best regards

Edit: Current formula by request

```
=IF(A2=0;0;IF($I$1=1;SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!L:L);IF($I$1=2;SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!L:L)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!M:M);IF($I$1=3;SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!L:L)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!M:M)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!N:N);IF($I$1=4;SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!L:L)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!M:M)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!N:N)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!O:O);IF($I$1=5;SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!L:L)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!M:M)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!N:N)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!O:O)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!P:P);IF($I$1=6;SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!L:L)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!M:M)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!N:N)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!O:O)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!P:P)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!Q:Q);IF($I$1=7;SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!L:L)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!M:M)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!N:N)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!O:O)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!P:P)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!Q:Q)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!R:R);IF($I$1=8;SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!L:L)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!M:M)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!N:N)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!O:O)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!P:P)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!Q:Q)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!R:R)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!S:S);IF($I$1=9;SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!L:L)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!M:M)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!N:N)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!O:O)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!P:P)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!Q:Q)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!R:R)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!S:S)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!T:T);IF($I$1=10;SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!L:L)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!M:M)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!N:N)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!O:O)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!P:P)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!Q:Q)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!R:R)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!S:S)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!T:T)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!U:U);IF($I$1=11;SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!L:L)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!M:M)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!N:N)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!O:O)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!P:P)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!Q:Q)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!R:R)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!S:S)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!T:T)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!U:U)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!V:V);IF($I$1=12;SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!L:L)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!M:M)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!N:N)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!O:O)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!P:P)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!Q:Q)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!R:R)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!S:S)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!T:T)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!U:U)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!V:V)+SUM.IF('Earnings'!A:A;A2;'Earnings'!W:W);"")))))))))))))
```

Comment: Why is June in the wrong place?  Why are August and September missing?

Comment: Please post the current formula for us to see what it does and replicate using a shorter version.

Comment: @Chronocidal Man, i went to quick with the months. It's been a long day, sorry

Comment: @ed2 I added the current formular - it's really long tho :(

Comment: Thanks. I agree. Try the suggested answer and let us know how you go.

Comment: Can't you just use an offset? You just calculate something like `=sum(A1:A1.Offset(0,amount_of_months))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `B16`, enter formula :

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B2,MATCH(A16,A3:A9,0),,,C12))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SUMIF is used to add the contents of a *single column* that match the criteria.

To achieve what you want, try this:

## To shorten the formula significantly

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$3:$A$9=$A$14)*(B3:K9))
```

I have guessed your row and column numbers, but if you can't get it working just post your row and column headings and I will troubleshoot it.

Alternatively, if you would like to add another table with cumulative earnings, you could do it quite easily.

## To provide cumulative earnings for each month for each person

For example, in B15 (or whatever the reference, we can't see your row/column number) you could have "Cumulative Jan", then fill right for a column for the cumulative earnings for each month. In that case B15 would say:

```
=SUM($B3:B3)
```

Then fill right and down.

This gives you cumulative earnings for any month for any person, in a table.

You could then do a lookup to that table if you wanted to, to return the matching value given the two inputs of person and month number.

Comment: While it wasn't the solution to this question, it was very helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad it could help. Give it an upvote to show future visitors it was helpful.